# Hide Android Voice Recognition Activity to run in background?

Tags: android, android-layout, voice-recognition

Is there a way to either

A) start the activity without opening up the GUI
B) start the VoiceRecognitionActivity behind my current activity, so the user does not notice?

Essentially, I'm not fond of how Voice Recognition disrupts the UX and would rather the user just see the words "listening" in my activity.  Android's a great OS and I think it deserves more beautiful apps!

I'm an Android newbie (as you can see from my question history) and very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A) start the activity without opening up the GUI

No. There is no such concept in Android.

> B) start the VoiceRecognitionActivity behind my current activity, so the user does not notice?

No. There is no such concept in Android.

> Essentially, I'm not fond of how Voice Recognition disrupts the UX

Bear in mind that what you want should be immaterial. What your *users* want is what matters.

You are welcome to attempt to use [`SpeechRecognizer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html) directly, though this is only possible on Android 2.2 and newer. On older versions of Android, you will have to settle for the standard voice recognition UI.

Comment: thanks. though, i disagree "what you want should be immaterial" - for first-time developers, we've got no users, just an idea.

Comment: @ehfeng: That's actually my point exactly. For "first-time developers", your inclination should be to follow the norms. You may think that "Voice Recognition disrupts the UX", but quite obviously lots of other people disagree, since that's the default implementation. If you have evidence of UX disruption *in the eyes of users*, by all means feel free to address it. Otherwise, please stick to platform UX conventions. Android apps' UX inconsistencies is a major user complaint. All you are doing is making that worse.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a voice service using SpeechRecognizer. However, the service still has to run in the UI thread. That is you can not create another thread in the service and let the recognizer runs there.